# How to add campaign tracking to a URL with an existing query string

Tags: url, query-string

I want to add the campaign tracking to a URL but it's already got a query string on it.

The existing URL is *www.mywebsite.com/?nomobile* and I want to add:

?utm_source=SOURCE&utm_medium=MEDIUM&utm_campaign=NAME

**Can you have two ?'s in a URL?** If I can't do this, what is the alternative?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

See the & character in the campaign tracking code? That's separating various different query string parameters. The ? starts the Query string, and then the & separates different parameters.

http://www.mywebsite.com/?nomobile&utm_source=SOURCE&utm_medium=MEDIUM&utm_campaign=NAME

Comment: No worries, we all have to start somewhere. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't have two ?. You can, rather, have as many & as you need.

Answer (score -1):

Only one ?; Then you seperate parameters with &;

Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). I hope this will explain things a little bit.